# Does this theorem has been proved yet?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I am having a little trouble to prove an hypothesis about Euclidean geometry, This happen because I am using an theorem about the theme that I don't know if is true, can anyone help me? Here is the fount of my problems:

If we take four distinct points, 'A', 'B', 'C' and 'D', being AB with an equal length of CD, the perpendicular bisector of AD is the same of BC.

edit1: I've forgot to say that $AB//CD$

Answer (score 0):

False.

Consider $A=(0,1), B=(2,0), C=(3,0), D=(1,1)$

Comment: i've forgot to say that AB // CD, sorry...

Comment: but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a parallelogram and the diagonals bisect each other. **If** the four points are collinear **then** the perpendicular bisectors are the same. Otherwise they are different.

Comment: so, if I take an parallelogram and take the Perpendicular bisector of his diagonals, will they be on the same point?

Comment: Yes. All the points are on the same line and the two bisectors are the same points, and so is the perpendicular bisectors.

Comment: ok, that helps, thank you.